# Using angular submit button causes redirect instead of calling function in SharePoint

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a form within my angular app (within SharePoint) that uses routing via hashbang, but when I click on a button in my form, it redirects to the root (like it can't resolve the URL so it uses the otherwise setting in my config), instead of executing the function.

Here is the HTML (my controller is defined in the routing):

```
<form name="newItem" class="form-horizontal" data-ng-submit="createItem()">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="itemtype">Type *</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <select class="form-control" id="itemtype" data-ng-model="selectedType"
                                data-ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in types" required>
                            <option style="display:none" value="">Select a type</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="title">Title *</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input class="form-control" name="title" id="title" type="text" data-ng-model="itemtitle" placeholder="Add your title (Limited to 70 characters)" data-ng-maxlength="70" required>
                        ({{70 - newItem.title.$viewValue.length}} Characters Remaining)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="body">Body *</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="body" id="body" data-ng-model="itembody" rows="4" placeholder="Add your body (Limited to 500 characters)" data-ng-maxlength="500" required> </textarea>
                        Your summary will be displayed as follows ({{500 - newItem.body.$viewValue.length}} Characters Remaining):<br /> {{itembody}}

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="newItem">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Here is my controller:

```
appControllers.controller('appItemPostCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'appItems', 'appTypes', function ($scope, $location, appItems, appTypes) {

var itemEntry = new appItems;
console.log(itemEntry);

 $scope.types = [];

 appTypes.query(function (typedata) {
     var itemTypes = typedata.value; 
    // Foreach type, push values into types array
    angular.forEach(itemTypes, function (typevalue, typekey) {

        $scope.types.push({
            label: typevalue.Title,
            value: typevalue.Title,
        });
    })
});


$scope.createItem = function () {

    itemEntry.Title = $scope.itemtitle;
    itemEntry.$save();

}

$scope.cancel = function () {

}

}]);
```

**UPDATE:** It appears that this is related to SharePoint (My Angular Form is in SharePoint), as even setting the button type to submit as follows triggers the refresh instead of running the function. SharePoint is wrapping everything in a form since it inherits from the Master page of the Web, so when I added two "Angular Forms" to the page, the first angular form was closing the tag on the SharePoint form so the second was able to work. Does anyone have a stable workaround (beyond creating a custom masterpage). Image as follows:

[image: SharePoint App HTML]

Comment: I believe I have isolated the issue, as SharePoint includes a form in the Masterpage, it is conflicting with my form by not allowing the form tag to even show in code. What is odd is that if I add two angular forms, the second will work as if the first angular form closes the SharePoint form. How frustrating...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by closing the  tag of SharePoint instead of creating a custom masterpage. Ex:

```
<!-- Close the default form tag put in place by SharePoint instead of creating a custom Masterpage without this element that requires increased permissions and complexity to deploy. Without this tag closed, the form below will not render properly -->
</form>

<div>

<form id="newItemForm" class="form-horizontal" data-ng-submit="createItem()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="itemtype">Type *</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <select class="form-control" id="itemtype" data-ng-model="selectedType"
                    data-ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in types" required>
                <option style="display:none" value="">Select a type</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="title">Title *</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input class="form-control" name="title" id="title" type="text" data-ng-model="itemtitle" placeholder="Add your title (Limited to 70 characters)" data-ng-maxlength="70" required>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="body">Body *</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="body" id="body" data-ng-model="itembody" rows="4" placeholder="Add your body (Limited to 500 characters)" data-ng-maxlength="500" required> </textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>-->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add type='button' to the buttons. I had this same problem before and assumed it was an angular bug of some kind.

Comment: That stops the redirect but the action is not occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Do both buttons exhibit this behavior or just the Submit button?

The submit button calls newItem from ng-click, but the name of the function in the js is actually createItem.

Comment: Yes, it happens on both buttons. If I add the type="button" to both it stops the behavior. the newItem reference is supposed to call the data-ng-submit="createItem()" on the form (I use this in other applications), but is not working.

Comment: If I change my buttons to this, the function works. I wonder why it works in another app, but not here via the submit on the entire form:                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="createItem()">Submit</button>